# get pixeldata faster without gtk purely with opencv

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am getting pixels from opencv camera frame with this code and then I am converting it to pixels (variable pixeldata) via pygtk. I think, it should be better to omit gtk step and convert it to the same pixeldata but purely with opencv, to save CPU time. Any idea please, how to do it faster directly with opencv?

```
_,frame = cam.read()
pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_data(frame, gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8, 800, 600, 2400)
pixeldata = pixbuf.get_pixels()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*variable pixeldata*"? `frame` is a numpy array and it already contains all the pixel data. You can get the image dimensions by `frame.shape`, and [iterate over all pixels](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/08/28/fast-optimized-for-pixel-loops-with-opencv-and-python/).

Comment: I need to get the same data output in variable "pixeldata" as I get when I use gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_data() and get_pixels() (as shown in my code sample). I thought if I could omit gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_data() and get_pixels() and somehow get the same output directly from opencv frame. 

So maybe to save some time without pixbuf_new_from_data and get_pixels transformation.